# Printing unique keys from nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a dictionary `dict_matches` with 2 inner dictionaries.

The structure of `dict_match` is as follows:

```
dict_match = {Query_ID:{Function_ID:{DB_ID:[func_ID]}}}
```

Within the top level of keys `Query_ID`, I loop through these and compare these against keys in a completely separate dict `query_count_dict` to determine the overlap of keys.

Within this loop I also navigate to the base dict in `dict_matches` in order to see what keys `DB_ID` the master key has 'matched' with. My problem is that this lower-level of keys `DB_ID` that correspond to the very top-level key `Query_ID` can be duplicated (and I only want to see the unique keys). I tried using the set() method but this actually split the string keys into their character components and printed the unique characters for each lower-level key. Any help appreciated!

See code below

```
for k,v in dict_match.items():
    if k in query_count_dict.keys():
        print(k)
        detection_query.append(k)

        print(len(dict_match[k])/int(query_count_dict[k]))

    if type(v) is dict:
        recursive_items(v)
```

where recursive_items is a function to navigate to the base dict:

```
def recursive_items(dictionary):
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        if type(v) is dict:
            recursive_items(v)
        else:
            print(set(k))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print all the unique keys by passing a list of keys in your recursive function, to store them as you navigate to the base. Then cast it to set to remove the duplicates.

```
def get_keys(dictionary, keys=[]):
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        keys.append(k)
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            get_keys(v, keys)
    return set(keys)

dict_match = {'A': {'A': {'B': [0], 'H': [0]}, 'D': {'C': [0], 'A': [0]}},
              'B': {'C': {'A': [0]}, 'G': {'A': [0]}},
              'C': {'A': {'E': [0]}, 'B': {'F': [0], 'A': [0]}, 'C': {'B': [0]}}}

print(get_keys(dict_match))
```

And it will output only the unique keys:

```
{'G', 'B', 'E', 'F', 'C', 'H', 'A', 'D'}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! This has definitely helped in obtaining only unique base keys however would it be possible to loop through the master keys and print out the unique base keys for each master key? ie in the example you have given, I'd like the output to be:

`{'B','H','A','C'} {'A'} {'E','A','F','B'}`

thanks in advance :)

Comment: for reference, my issue is that when I loop through the master keys, the unique base keys keep getting appended to the `keys` list even though I recall the function for each master key